# Como atualizar a página automaticamente ao salvar o projeto?

Tags: html5, node.js

Como atualizar a página automaticamente ao salvar o projeto para automatizar o trabalho?. 
Para automatizar mais o projeto como nos projetos do cordova.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o que procura é o [Nodemon](http://nodemon.io/):

> O Nodemon é um utilitário que monitoriza quaisquer alterações no código fonte e reinicia automaticamente o seu servidor. Perfeito para o desenvolvimento. [...] Basta usar o Nodemon em vez do Node para executar o seu código e, agora, o seu processo será reiniciado automaticamente quando o código for alterado.

Pode instalar globalmente na sua máquina via [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/) usando o comando `npm install -g nodemon`. Desta forma fica disponível em todos os projetos que trabalhar na sua máquina mas nunca fica nas dependências dos projetos.

Também podes instalar o `nodemon` como dependência de `dev` nos seus projetos usando `npm install nodemon --save-dev`.